# Android Studio Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

How do I fix this Error?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
is also present at [com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.
```

Comment: You are using multiple versions of the Support Library, either directly or through transitive dependencies. Take a look at your module's `build.gradle` file (e.g., `app/build.gradle`).

Comment: You are using multiple versions of Support Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a different version of Google Support libraries.

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1
```

Also

```
com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1
```

Use common version for both libraries. that will help.

I think you are using **Compile SDK 26**, so use both libraries like below.

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1
com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.0.0-alpha1
```